Query to Get All Metrics in Azure App Insights
I am trying to make a query to get all metrics in Azure Application Insights logs in one run. Need some help to get all metrics details with specific Columns (Metric Name, Avg, Unique, Sum). I am trying to use "summarize" and "union" operators for all the metrics in Application Insights log analytics but getting different view and results from the desired and expected view shown in the image attached. I am new also to Kusto Query Language so appreciate help from the community. 

Can you share the sample data as an example with cols.

What about this query?
customMetrics
| project timestamp, name, value
| summarize avg(value), sum(value) by name

Or a little more complex:
pageViews
| project session_Id, operation_Id, user_Id
| join (
customMetrics
| project timestamp, name, value, user_Id, operation_Id, session_Id
) on session_Id
| summarize avg(value), sum(value) by name, user_Id, session_Id
| summarize avg(avg_value), sum(sum_value) by name, session_Id

Anything else you want to see?
